# The name 'FirebaseAuthExceptions' isn't a type and can't be used in an on-catch clause

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I Got This Weird Error:

"The name 'FirebaseAuthExceptions' isn't a type and can't be used in an on-catch clause."

```
TextButton(
       onPressed: () async { 
       final email = _email.text;
        final password = _password.text;
      try { final userCredential =
             await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword (
           email: email,
           password: password,
       );
         print(userCredential);
         } on FirebaseAuthExceptions catch (e){
         If (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
         print("User is not Found");
        } Else if (e.code == 'wrong password') {
         print("Wrong Password");
         }
         }
         },
        child: Text("LogIn"),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be `FirebaseAuthException` instead of `FirebaseAuthExceptions`(extra s is the typo) and `if` , `else` should be start with small letter on dart

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  final email = _email.text;
  final password = _password.text;
  try {
    final userCredential =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    print(userCredential);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
      print("User is not Found");
    } else if (e.code == 'wrong password') {
      print("Wrong Password");
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FirebaseAuthException instead of FirebaseAuthExceptions, remove 's'

Good Day!!!